Websphere Application Server JVM Logs
From the management console, we can set up the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) log settings:
Troubleshooting > Logs and Trace > server_name > JVM Logs

I have a requirement to check the values set in the management console from the configuration files (e.g., Log file rotation, Maximum Number of Historical Log Files). For instance, we can check security.xml to verify the security configuration, including all user IDs and password data, from this path: config/cells/cell_name/
So, how can I find these parameters, and in which configuration file? I have looked everywhere but have found no clues.

Server logging configuration is found within your profile, in config/cells/<cellname>/nodes/<nodename>/servers/<servername>/server.xml
Among the many <services> elements is one called "traceservice:TraceService" that specifies trace settings and has a sub-element for the trace.log location. Separately, there are <errorStreamRedirect> and <outputStreamRedirect> elements for SystemErr.log and SystemOut.log, respectively.
Native logs are configured within the <processDefinition> element that defines low-level JVM settings, in the <ioRedirect> sub-element.

is there any way to set log rotation into every 6months because i can't find this option in the console?

Nope - log rotation options are size-based, not date-based (and not available at all for the native logs).
